# jquery auto-complete displaying search box empty in IE11 and chrome

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am creating a search bar using jquery autocomplete.

Here is my autocomplete code:

```
$('#search_bar input#search_box').autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "service/search.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {action:'getSuggest',categoryId:$('#search_bar #selectSearch').val(),searchText:request.term},
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data['0'], function( Convalue ) {
                return {
                label: Convalue['name'],
                value: Convalue['name'],
                id: Convalue['ID']
                }
            }));
            },
            error: function (e,a,b) {
            jAlert('error in searching products'+e,'Failed');
            }
        });
        },
        cacheLength: 0,
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
        event.preventDefault();     
        $('#search_bar input#search_box').val();
        if(ui.item)
        {
            var categoryId=$('#search_bar #selectSearch').val();
            if(categoryId=='0'){
            if(ui.item.id=='1')
                location.replace('custom-granule.php');
            else if(ui.item.id=='2')
                location.replace('custom-raw.php');
            else
                location.replace('product-info.php?id='+ui.item.id);
            }
            else if(categoryId=='1')
            location.replace('product-symptom.php?id='+ui.item.id);
            else if(categoryId=='2')
            location.replace('product-pattern.php?patternId='+ui.item.id);
            else
            location.replace('product-category.php?id='+ui.item.id);
        }
        else {
            jAlert("Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        }
        }
    });
```

Now my problem is that :  IE and Chrome displaying Alert message 'Searchbox is empty' on search. IE and chrome is not consistent in displaying this alert box. Sometime it show and other time it doesn't. FF seems to be OK.

Answer (score 0):

## search_bar input#search_box

This selector with # operator may not be select right element in every browser. you can test it in chrome Console by F12

Comment: I think this isn't a problem with selector. Because, some times it does the search correctly, If I repeatedly search for more than 10 times, then it shows 'empty search' in IE and chrome.

Comment: I see same behavior in my mvc project yesterday than i just remove # character from tagname i write uniq id to the element and it worked for me. I am not sure but try this